# run a web project developed in Java run on both windows and Linux platform

Tags: java, windows, linux, cross-platform

I have a web project developed in java. I am using the Windows platform and accessing the project from the Windows machine itself. How can I make the project run on a Linux machine? I am using jboss server and deploying the project.

Regards

Comment: Maybe if you just install JBoss on the Linux machine, it will solve your problem, no?

Answer (score 4):

Java is Cross-Platform, MySQL also. You can have your application server running on one server and the database on another. You can even have your Appserver on Linux and your database on Windows and your client on MacOS.

If you run into any specific problem, please let us know, but everything should be transparent unless you wrote some very bad Java code ...

Answer (score 0):

Java is a Cross-Platform language.  Just deploy your JAR/WAR/EAR in a JBOSS running on a Linux Box.

Answer (score 0):

Java can run on many platforms only if any platform specific coding is not done for example file separator are different in windows, linux and Mac.

You need Jboss for linux and deploy your web application it should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Java can run on many plarforms including linux and windows. You can develop project anywhere and run on any server.

I suggest you, install a linux on [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and deploy it on linux directly. Also you can try [cruise control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) for deploy automatically.